# How to handle BigTable Scan InvalidChunk exceptions?

Tags: python, google-cloud-bigtable, happybase

I am trying to scan BigTable data where some rows are 'dirty' - but this fails depending on the scan, causing (serialization?) **InvalidChunk** exceptions.
the code is as follows:

```
from google.cloud import bigtable
from google.cloud import happybase
client = bigtable.Client(project=project_id, admin=True)
instance = client.instance(instance_id)
connection = happybase.Connection(instance=instance)
table = connection.table(table_name)

for key, row in table.scan(limit=5000):  #BOOM!
    pass
```

leaving out some columns or limiting the rows to less or specifying the start and stop keys, allows the scan to succeed. 
I cannot detect which values are problematic from the stacktrace - it varies across columns - the scan just fails. This makes it problematic to clean the data at source.

When I leverage the python debugger, I see that the chunk (which is of type **google.bigtable.v2.bigtable_pb2.CellChunk**) has no value (it is NULL / undefined):

```
ipdb> pp chunk.value
b''
ipdb> chunk.value_size
0
```

I can confirm this with the HBase shell from the rowkey ( i got from **self._row.row_key**)

So the question becomes: **How can a BigTable scan filter-out columns which have undefined / empty / null value ?**

I get the same problem from both google cloud APIs that return generators which internally stream data as chunks over gRPC:

- google.cloud.**happybase**.table.Table#   **scan**()
- google.cloud.**bigtable**.table.Table#    **read_rows**().**consume_all**()

the abbreviated stacktrace is as follows:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
InvalidChunk                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-48-922c8127f43b> in <module>()
      1 row_gen = table.scan(limit=n) 
      2 rows = []
----> 3 for kvp in row_gen:
      4     pass
.../site-packages/google/cloud/happybase/table.py in scan(self, row_start, row_stop, row_prefix, columns, timestamp, include_timestamp, limit, **kwargs)
    391         while True:
    392             try:
--> 393                 partial_rows_data.consume_next()
    394                 for row_key in sorted(rows_dict):
    395                     curr_row_data = rows_dict.pop(row_key)

.../site-packages/google/cloud/bigtable/row_data.py in consume_next(self)
    273         for chunk in response.chunks:
    274 
--> 275             self._validate_chunk(chunk)
    276 
    277             if chunk.reset_row:

.../site-packages/google/cloud/bigtable/row_data.py in _validate_chunk(self, chunk)
    388             self._validate_chunk_new_row(chunk)
    389         if self.state == self.ROW_IN_PROGRESS:
--> 390             self._validate_chunk_row_in_progress(chunk)
    391         if self.state == self.CELL_IN_PROGRESS:
    392             self._validate_chunk_cell_in_progress(chunk)

.../site-packages/google/cloud/bigtable/row_data.py in _validate_chunk_row_in_progress(self, chunk)
    368         self._validate_chunk_status(chunk)
    369         if not chunk.HasField('commit_row') and not chunk.reset_row:
--> 370             _raise_if(not chunk.timestamp_micros or not chunk.value)
    371         _raise_if(chunk.row_key and
    372                   chunk.row_key != self._row.row_key)

.../site-packages/google/cloud/bigtable/row_data.py in _raise_if(predicate, *args)
    439     """Helper for validation methods."""
    440     if predicate:
--> 441         raise InvalidChunk(*args)

InvalidChunk:
```

**Can you show me how to scan BigTable from Python, ignoring / logging dirty rows that raise InvalidChunk?** 
(**try ... except** wont work around the generator,which is in the google cloud API **row_data PartialRowsData** class)

**Also, can you show me code to chunk stream a table scan in BigTable?**
HappyBase **batch_size** & **scan_batching** don't seem to be supported.

Comment: This sounds like a bug in the library or the service.  There shouldn't actually ever be an invalid chunk.  https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-python

Answer (score 1):

This was likely due to this bug: https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-python/issues/2980

The bug has been fixed, so this should no longer be an issue.